# Detect when a record is inserted or updated in oracle materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g, materialized-views

When updating an existing record, is it deleted from a materialized view and then re-inserted?

My problem is that I update an existing record and the trigger is being executed. I only want this trigger to be fired for NEW records.

I'm working with an Oracle materialized view. I have a trigger like:

```
create or replace trigger my_view_trigger
    after insert on my_materialized_view
    for each row
        begin
            --handle new record
        end;
```

I have also tried changing the "after insert" part to be "after insert or update" and had a body in the begins block like:

```
if inserting then
    --handle new record
elseif updating then
    --handle modification of existing record
end if;
```

But every update was seen as an insert. Is there a way to detect updates in a materialized view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered materialized view logs? There is much seeded functionality around monitoring tables which the materialized view is dependent on using materialized view log files (explicitly designed for this purpose).

For instance, I have a log file for my Oracle Apps table,inv.mtl_system_items_b.
Next, if I want to monitor DML changes to the table, I just query the log file:

```
 SELECT m_row$$
FROM INV.MLOG$_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
WHERE DMLTYPE$$ = 'I'
AND SNAPTIME$$ >= TRUNC(sysdate));
```

The log file keeps track of the DML type with the column, DMLTYPES$$ (I for insert, U for Update, ...).

Now suppose I want to know the exact records being inserted today, I might do something like this:

```
   SELECT *
FROM INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
WHERE rowid IN
  (SELECT m_row$$
  FROM INV.MLOG$_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
  WHERE DMLTYPE$$ = 'I'
  AND SNAPTIME$$ >= TRUNC(sysdate)
  )
```

One can then modify your triggers using some variation of a query monitoring these tables which the materialized view is dependent on.  There is great value in leveraging this seeded functionality (no need to re-create the wheel).

With respect to Triggers on materialized views, there are some issues:

-Oracle generally advises against this (see trigger documentation), except on updatable materialized views.

-An update of a row in a materialized view might be done as a DELETE+INSERT

See Tom Kyte's writing on this ([https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:672989600346945045](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:672989600346945045)).

Generally, this is discouraged.

Comment: For triggers on regular tables I'm able to easily detect whether the record in question is an insert or update - why is it ALWAYS an insert for materialized views?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have a fast, complete or force refresh approach to your materialized view?  Based on your description, it sounds like a complete approach (where it is truncated during the refresh process).

Comment: I have a fast refresh approach to the materialized view. I don't disagree that your proposed solution resolves my problem, it just seems odd to have to go digging in the materialized view logs when in other circumstances I'm able to use "if updating."

Comment: See my updates to my answer.  Your intuition about inserts resulting in delete+insert scenarios can happen.